# After a restart due to a system crash the ethernet interface is disappeared. How to restore it?

Tags: networking, network-manager, ethernet, 19.10, ifconfig

I am not so into Linux and I am experiencing a very strange problem with a Linux 19.10 system on which I am working into VmWare workstation (but I suppose that it is not a VMware related problem).

The problem is that I had to restart the system due to a crash that freeze the system. After the restart I have no more Internet connection.

Performing the **ifconfig** command into the shell I obtain:

```
developer@developer-virtual-machine:/etc/network$ ifconfig
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Loopback locale)
        RX packets 2508  bytes 186240 (186.2 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2508  bytes 186240 (186.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

So it seems that for some reason it loose the ethernet interface used by VmWare to connect in NAT mode.

I tried to restart the system (also the host Windows machine on which VMWare is installed) but I still have this problem. How can I try to fix it?

**EDIT-1:** Performing **sudo lshw -C network** I obtain this output:

```
developer@developer-virtual-machine:~$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password di developer: 
  *-network DISABLED        
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82545EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1
       bus info: pci@0000:02:01.0
       logical name: ens33
       version: 01
       serial: 00:50:56:3a:4b:1e
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: pm pcix bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical logical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000 driverversion=7.3.21-k8-NAPI duplex=full latency=0 link=no mingnt=255 multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:19 memory:fd5c0000-fd5dffff memory:fdff0000-fdffffff ioport:2000(size=64) memory:fd500000-fd50ffff
```

It seems that the networking is disabled

Comment: I would look at what hardware is seen (`sudo lshw -C network` for example to list hardware devices of class network), but I suspect your issue is HOST related (either VMWare setting or w10) thus off-topic here.

Comment: @guiverc posted the output of "sudo lshw -C network" at the end of my original post. Reading the output it seems to me that networing is disabled into this Linux machine. I don't think that the problem is related to VMWare because I have other VMs that works fine

Comment: Yep you're right; if it was HOST config as I suspected you'd not see the results in `lshw`, which did show the problem (DISABLED).   Well done for fixing !.   Can I suggest you change your manual from cosmic [18.10] to eoan [19.10] , ie. http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/eoan/man1/nmcli.1.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved myself. Maybe it can help someone else:

1) I discovered that Ubuntu 19.10 by default is not defining the network interfaces by the **/etc/network/interfaces** file. This file doesn't exist.
To manage the network interfaces it is using the network manager: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man1/nmcli.1.html

2) First of all I list the interfaces by this command: **sudo nmcli device show**

```
[sudo] password di developer: 
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         ens33
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         00:50:56:3A:4B:1E
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          10 (non gestito)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         lo
GENERAL.TYPE:                           loopback
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         00:00:00:00:00:00
GENERAL.MTU:                            65536
GENERAL.STATE:                          10 (non gestito)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         127.0.0.1/8
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         ::1/128
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = ::1/128, nh = ::, mt = 256
```

As you can see the ethernet network interface neamed **ens33** is at the moment not handled (in italian "non gestito"), so at the moment is disabled.

3) I enabled it by

```
nmcli networking on
```

now it works fine

Answer (score 1):

Here is what fixed the same problem for me (AndreaNoboli's answer sadly didn't help):

check /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf and /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/ to see if there's a managed=false entry which could be changed.

I got it from an only tangentially related issue elsewhere: https://access.redhat.com/discussions/6278791, but it worked perfectly for me.